# How to convert XLSX to XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I have a problem. I'm trying to generate a report automatically with JasperReports using Java. The thing is I need a data source that is compatible with JasperReports that's why I've chosen XML. So, does anyone have any idea about how to convert XLSX file to XML file using Java so that I can use that file in creating the report?

Thanks

Comment: Try this: https://www.zamzar.com/convert/xlsx-to-xml/
It's the first result I got when googling

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm looking for a method to do it using java without including any web service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using docx4j - https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

Sample code :

```
File file = new File("C:/Desktop/excelfile.xlsx");
SpreadsheetMLPackage excelMLPackage = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(file);
excelMLPackage.save(new File("C:/Desktop/xmlFile.xml"));
```

Good luck.

Comment: I guess you want to save one of the worksheet parts (which is already XML), as opposed to converting the zip to Flat OPC XML.  But even this might not be satisfactory, if cell content is a reference to the shared string table, formatted, or worse, calculated.  Perhaps you'll want to convert the worksheet to a simple row/column format with references to shared strings resolved, numbers formatted etc.   https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/xlsx4j/org/xlsx4j/samples/CellContentExtractor.java may help